# Remove slide delay vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some section with infinite carousel using vanilla js.
My logic is based on using justify-content:flex-end for previous slide and justify-content:flex-start for next one.
My carousel has default justify-content:flex-start and it works fine when slides to next, but  there is some render delay if I'm using slide to prev.
It's because of using justify-content:flex-end for prev, but how to get rid of delay?
This is my code

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel')
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev')
const next = document.querySelector('.next')

let direction

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (direction === -1) {
        slider.appendChild(slider.lastElementChild)
        direction = 1
    }
    direction = 1
    carousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(20%)'
})

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    direction = -1
    carousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(-20%)'
})

slider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (direction === -1) {
        slider.appendChild(slider.firstElementChild)
    } else if (direction === 1) {
        slider.prepend(slider.lastElementChild)
    }

    slider.style.transition = 'none'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(0)'
    setTimeout(() => {
        slider.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s'
    })
})
```

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 80px 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 70px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.prev {
  left: 20px;
}

.next {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="item"> Item 1</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 2</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 3</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 4</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 5</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 1</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 2</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 3</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 4</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach. Your code is appending (and prepending) elements after the slider has transitioned. Because of the overflow:hidden you don't notice it happen when it appends to the end of the slider but you notice when it prepends to the start which is why you see it render after the translation.
So you could move the slider 20% to the left so you don't see when the element is prepended and not change most of your code.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel')
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev')
const next = document.querySelector('.next')

let direction

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (direction === -1) {
        slider.appendChild(slider.lastElementChild)
        direction = 1
    }
    direction = 1
    // removed - carousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(20%)'
})

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    direction = -1
    // removed - carousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(-20%)'
})

slider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (direction === -1) {
        slider.appendChild(slider.firstElementChild)
    } else if (direction === 1) {
        slider.prepend(slider.lastElementChild)
    }

    slider.style.transition = 'none'
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(0)'
    setTimeout(() => {
        slider.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s'
    })
})
```

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 80px 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Only change */ margin-left: -20%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 70px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.prev {
  left: 20px;
}

.next {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="prev">Prev</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="item"> Item 1</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 2</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 3</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 4</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 5</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 6</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 7</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 9</div>
            <div class="item"> Item 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```